# AWK: How to merge CSV files and eliminate rows that contain certain values?

Tags: csv, awk

I have hundreds of CSV files. Each CSV file is similar to this:

```
| KEYWORD | NUMBER OF COMPS | AVGE M E (K) | GS/M | EST. A SE/M | C CORE |
|---------|-----------------|--------------|------|-------------|--------|
| Apples  | 311             | 12           | N/A  | <100        | 10     |
| Bananas | >1,200          | 737          | N/A  | 490         | 88     |
| Oranges | 48              | 184          | N/A  | N/A         | 1      |
| Fruits  | 161             | 94           | N/A  | -           | 6      |
```

(I have posted this in table format, to make it more readable, but the CSV data is at the bottom of this post).

All the CSV files have the same header row. Only the data is different.

I would like to do the following:

1. Merge all the CSV files together, but only have 1 header row.
2. Omit any rows where `EST. A SE/M` (Column 5) contains any of the following data: `<100`, `N/A` or `-`

### Notes about the Data

Sometimes the some or even all cells in the CSV file are wrapped in quotation marks.
Other times they are not. 
Sometimes the first column (keyword) may contain multiple words or accented characters.

---

### My code so far

This code merges all the CSV files into 1 without only one heading

```
awk '(NR == 1) || (FNR > 1)' *.csv > ^0-output.csv
```

This works perfectly.

However, I am not sure how to delete the unwanted rows after the merge.
So far I have this:

```
awk '$5 !~ /(<100|N\/A|-)/' ^0-output.csv > ^0-output.csv
```

But when I use this code, it just produces a blank file.
Plus, I am not sure if there is a way to integrate it in the first line, so it does everything with a single command.

---

### Notes

Here is how the data looks in CSV format

**Sample1.csv**

```
KEYWORD,NUMBER OF COMPS,AVGE M E (K),GS/M,EST. A SE/M,C CORE
Apples,311,12,N/A,<100,10
Bananas,">1,200",737,N/A,490,88
Oranges,48,184,N/A,N/A,1
Fruits,161,94,N/A,-,63
```

**Sample2.csv**

```
KEYWORD,NUMBER OF COMPS,AVGE M E (K),GS/M,EST. A SE/M,C CORE
Dino,588,67,N/A,888,234
Thunder,">1,200",211,N/A,<100,77
Ninja,95,37,N/A,-,878
```

**Sample3.csv**

```
KEYWORD,NUMBER OF COMPS,AVGE M E (K),GS/M,EST. A SE/M,C CORE
Blur,84,2454,N/A,-,234
```

**Sample4.csv**

```
"KEYWORD","NUMBER OF COMPS","AVGE M E (K)","GS/M","EST. A SE/M","C CORE"
"hedgehog rolls ròund",32,481,N/A,"878",13
"Clever Fox jumps Hîgh",233,83,N/A,"<100",12
"Bear à lot",122,35,N/A,"-",11
"kitten hîgh life","121","673","32","N/A","15"
```

Please note: The actual files that the finished script will be used on will have a variety of file names. They will NOT always follow the pattern of sample 1, sample 2 etc.

---

### Expected Output

**Expected output: (CSV format)**

```
KEYWORD,NUMBER OF COMPS,AVGE M E (K),GS/M,EST. A SE/M,C CORE
Bananas,">1,200",737,N/A,490,88
Dino,588,67,N/A,888,234
"hedgehog rolls ròund",32,481,N/A,"878",13
```

(Note: It doesn't matter if the expected output keeps the wrapping quote marks as the final CSV file is opened in Apple Numbers)

**Expected output: (Readable format)**

```
| KEYWORD | NUMBER OF COMPS | AVGE M E (K) | GS/M | EST. A SE/M | C CORE |
|---------|-----------------|--------------|------|-------------|--------|
| Bananas | >1,200          | 737          | N/A  | 490         | 88     |
| Dino    | 588             | 67           | N/A  | 888         | 234    |
| hedgehog rolls ròund    | 588             | 67           | N/A  | 888         | 234    |
```

Environment:
I am using Mac OS X 10.14.6. I am unable to install other versions of awk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me like you're only interested in testing the 2nd-last field and neither that nor the last field can contain commas so just count field numbers from the end instead of from the beginning of each line and then you don't care whether earlier fields contain commas or not. Given that, this will work using any awk:

```
$ awk -F',' '(NR==1) || (FNR>1 && $(NF-1)!~/^"?(<100|N\/A|-)"?$/)' *.csv
KEYWORD,NUMBER OF COMPS,AVGE M E (K),GS/M,EST. A SE/M,C CORE
Bananas,">1,200",737,N/A,490,88
Dino,588,67,N/A,888,234
"hedgehog rolls ròund",32,481,N/A,"878",13
```

Answer (score 4):

***EDIT:*** As per OP's comments there could be a comma in between `"` too, so to handle that its better to use `FPAT`, written and tested with GNU `awk`.

```
awk -v FPAT='[^,]*|"[^"]+"'  '
{ sub(/\r$/,"") }
FNR==1{
  if(NR==1){ print }
  next
}
$5=="<100"||$5=="N/A"||$5=="-"{
  next
}
1
' *.csv
```

---

---

Could you please try following, written and tested with GNU `awk` on shown samples only.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  FS=OFS=","
}
FNR==1{
  if(NR==1){ print }
  next
}
$5=="<100"||$5=="N/A"||$5=="-"{ next }
1
'  *.csv
```

OR in case your values can contain something else also and you want to use regex to match the values which you want to neglect then try following.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  FS=OFS=","
}
FNR==1{
  if(NR==1){ print }
  next
}
$5~/<100/ || $5~/N\/A/ || $5~/-/{ next }
1
'  *.csv
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                                        ##Starting awk program from here.
BEGIN{                                       ##Starting BEGIN section of this program from here.
  FS=OFS=","                                 ##Setting field separator as comma here.
}
FNR==1{                                      ##Checking condition if its firt line of current Input_file then do following.
  if(NR==1){ print }                         ##If its very first line of very first Input_file then print that line.
  next                                       ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
$5=="<100"||$5=="N/A"||$5=="-"{ next }       ##Checking condition if 5th field contains either <100 OR N/A OR - then skip all further statements.
1                                            ##awk'sh way to print the current line.
'  *.csv                                     ##Passing all .csv files to awk program from here.
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220922/discussion-between-big-smile-and-ravindersingh13).

Answer (score 4):

You may just add merge 2 conditions into one using `&&` :

```
awk -F, 'NR==1 || (FNR>1 && $5 !~ /^(<100|N\/A|-)$/)' *.csv > output.csv
```

Here `$5 !~ /^(<100|N\/A|-)$/)` will skip a row if `$5` is `<100` or `-` or `N/A`. It is important to use regex anchors `^` and `$` to avoid matching unwanted string such as `1000` or `AB-123`.

---

It seems you have a comma in double quotes also in file1.csv. In that case following `gnu-awk` command should work from you:

```
awk -v FPAT='"[^"]*"|[^,]*' '
NR == 1 || (FNR > 1 && $5 !~ /^(<100|N\/A|-)*$/)' *.csv > output.csv
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220921/discussion-between-anubhava-and-big-smile).